# Where does the name "Workshop" come from?

Tags: american-english

I have searched, found no answers, but why is a workshop called a workshop?

In academia, workshops are being held where you learn stuff and calculate stuff. It has nothing to do with a shop (where you buy stuff) and not so much work IMO. So why workshop?

Comment: A *shop* (small building) where one *works*. How, may I ask, did you search?

Comment: @Susan Confusion may arise from the fact that in Britain the term 'shop', as well as meaning 'a small building' is most frequently used to mean a retail premises. The English were, after all, said by Napoleon, to have been 'a nation of shopkeepers'. A place where goods are sold, is the lead meaning in the UK and across a large part of the world where Britain has held influence. In parts of Asia, for example, few would perhaps think of 'shop' as anything other than that. Hence 'workshop' might be confusing to a person unfamiliar with the wider meaning of 'shop'.

Comment: @WS2 - the common language problem again. Thank you, I did not know that. (But take, then, a milliner's shop. Isn't there a workplace in the back? Isn't that a workshop?) In the US, teens take *shop* in high school.

Comment: Please see my edit. Workshop= you buy work? I don't get it.

Comment: Ahh. This is clearer now. A workshop is a place to work with one's hands; it is **hands on**. In academia, *workshops* are intensive, small group studies with a higher teacher-to-student ratio. Like a mini-apprenticeship. As if one studied from a master craftsman in his workshop.

Comment: @Susan Oxford Dictionaries gives 2 meanings of the noun, 'shop'. Significantly first (and it doesn't indicate this as being uniquely British) is 'a building or part of a building where goods or services are sold: e.g. a video shop, a barber shop. Meaning 2 is' a place where things are manufactured or repaired; a workshop; an auto-repair shop.

Comment: @WS2 - We say *video store*. A barber *shop* is such because there is manual labor going on, as is also the case in beauty shop. Sometimes, men's stores are *shops* because it's manlier. It is ubiquitous enough that when *shop* is in the title of a *store*, it's usually named *Ye Olde Shoppe* or some such, but with a -pe to distinguish it from a lowly *shop*. Shop is a common verb, but we usually do our *shopping* in stores. In this, I am using my native country's tongue, not its dictionary. I'm sure there are areas where *shop* means store. But I haven't lived there.

Comment: @Susan You use 'coffee-shop', and you go 'shopping' don't you? 'We have only recently taken on 'coffee-shop', e.g. Costa or Starbucks. Traditionally one of those would have been a 'café', pronounced 'caff' in Britain, some with names like 'Kosy Korner Kaff'. They were usually run by nice ladies who knew how to make a perfect cup of tea and with splendid home-made buns. They were vastly superior, and more economical to today's disgusting offerings I have mentioned.

Comment: @WS2 - manual labor. It's not much but they grind, weigh, brew, package, etc. Same with sandwich shops, butcher shops, chop shops. We should agree to disagree. Stores are not usually called shops. We *shop* in stores.

Comment: @Susan We use 'department store' to mean somewhere like Selfridges, Harrods and their lesser equivalents such as John Lewis, who are in every large town or city. But we do not talk of a 'grocery store', those are 'supermarkets'. But now that companies like Tesco and Sainsbury's have got into small neighborhood versions I am not sure whether to call them 'shops'. No name yet seems to have become settled.

Comment: @Susan That is interesting. It had never before occurred to me that the only shops which are called shops in America are ones where work is done on the premises. It is also interesting that you would say 'butcher shop' whilst we would say 'butcher's shop'. That difference seems to be saying something too.

Comment: In Academia, they call it a workshop because it sounds better than 'expenses paid vacation'

Comment: I think medica's hands-on comment says it all.  As for origins, I'm assuming it comes from the old days when you had a craft workplace in the back of your building and a retail store in the front to sell the results.  We still have that today in my town.

Answer (score 1):

Just to solidify what is already in the comments:

There is a bit of divergence on the understanding on the word 'shop'. It can be a place where things are sold (or going to buy them) or it can be a place where work (labour) is done.

A 'workshop' is a place where hands on work is done such as a blacksmith's workshop or a carpentry workshop, etc. Sometimes workshop will be shortened to just 'shop', such as 'shop class' which takes place in a workshop or simply 'shop'.

When brought into an area like a white collar job or academia, it is meant to reflect the 'hands on' nature of the work, not just listening to a lecture or some sort of passive activity.